# In woocommerce single product page I want to display products from same brand with the brand image of current product in single product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce, woocommerce-theming

The problem is my code is working fine, it shows brand image and products form the same brand fo single product page , but it also shows products which have their catalog visibility hidden, can someone please help me with this , so my code doesn't show products which have catalog visibility hidden.

here's my code for the reference :-

```
`<div class="brand-section">
    <?php
    // Get the current product
    global $product;

    // Get the product brand term (replace 'product_brand' with your actual brand taxonomy)
    $brand_term = wp_get_post_terms($product->get_id(), 'product_brand', array('fields' => 'ids'));

    // Display the brand image
    if (!empty($brand_term)) {
        $brand_id = $brand_term[0];
        $brand_image_id = get_term_meta($brand_id, 'brand_image', true);
        if (!empty($brand_image_id)) {
            echo '<div class="brand-image">';
            echo '<img src="' . esc_url(wp_get_attachment_image_url($brand_image_id, 'full')) . '" alt="' . esc_attr(get_term($brand_id)->name) . '">';
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }
    ?>

    <?php`
    // Display other products from the same brand
    if (!empty($brand_term)) {
        add_filter('woocommerce_product_query_tax_query', 'custom_exclude_hidden_products', 10, 2);

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => 4, // Show only 4 products
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_brand',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => $brand_term,
                ),
            ),
            'post__not_in' => array($product->get_id()), // Exclude the current product
        );

        $brand_query = new WP_Query($args);

        remove_filter('woocommerce_product_query_tax_query', 'custom_exclude_hidden_products', 10);

        if ($brand_query->have_posts()) {
            echo '<div class="other-products-from-brand">';
            echo '<h3 class="other-products-heading">Other Products from ' . esc_html(get_term($brand_id)->name) . '</h3>';
            while ($brand_query->have_posts()) {
                $brand_query->the_post();
                // Display other product information (e.g., product image, title, price, add to cart button)
                echo '<div class="product-item">';
                echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_post_thumbnail() . '</a>';
                echo '<h4><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></h4>';
                echo '<div class="price">' . wc_price(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_regular_price', true)) . '</div>';
                echo '<div class="add-to-cart-button">' . do_shortcode('[add_to_cart id="' . get_the_ID() . '"]') . '</div>';
                echo '</div>';
            }
            echo '</div>';
            wp_reset_postdata();
        }
    }

    // Custom function to exclude hidden products from the query
    function custom_exclude_hidden_products($tax_query, $query) {
        if ($query->is_main_query() && is_singular('product')) {
            $tax_query[] = array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => array('exclude-from-catalog', 'exclude-from-search', 'outofstock'),
                'operator' => 'NOT IN',
            );
        }
        return $tax_query;
    }
    ?>
</div>`
```

generally the products that are grouped within a different product and have catalog visibility hidden are getting shown as output

I tried using different visibility taxonomies but nothing works, the code should output products which only have visibility set to catalog & search & not display products with catalog visibility hidden

Comment: It doesn't make much sense that you are trying to use the `woocommerce_product_query_tax_query` filter in the first place here, IMHO. You are not trying to manipulate a query that is outside of the scope of your template file, you are _making_ the query yourself right in there. So whatever additional parameters need adding, you can add _directly_ to your `$args` array there.